# How to delete texture above from under texture?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making a scratchcard mini-game and I want to make scratchcard texture erase-able with other texture, I have scratchcard texture (colorful) and a mask texture (circle while) I'am trying to make so that when mask texture is on scratchcard texture it become a 'hole' you see trough it and see the background.

I've tried making it with blending

This is the code I found on stackoverflow from a different topic which I tried to modify, but it didnt seem to work.

```
//         draw our destination image
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.end();

        // remember SpriteBatch's current functions
        int srcFunc = batch.getBlendSrcFunc();
        int dstFunc = batch.getBlendDstFunc();

        // Let's enable blending
        batch.enableBlending();
        batch.begin();

        // blend them
        batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
        image.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX() - (image.getWidth() / 2), -Gdx.input.getY() + (1280 * GambleRPG.SCALE_Y) - (image.getHeight() / 2));
        image.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        // Reset
        batch.end();
        batch.begin();
        batch.setBlendFunction(srcFunc, dstFunc);
```

Comment: Use Pixmap and fillCirle method

Comment: @icarumbas But it would be slow for the phones etc would it ? If i erase the pixels for each touch

Comment: If you're making a scratch card game, I doubt there will be much else using the resources so it shouldn't slow it down that much if at all.